# Indentation Error Python Not Working

Tags: python, indentation

Im trying to run my code and there is an

```
File "C:/trcrt/trcrt.py", line 42
def checkInternet():
^
IndentationError: unexpected unindent
```

The code supposed to check for the traceroute to a website... i know... its not very smart but its what i was told to do
Ive checked the code using pep8 and eveything is seems to be fine...

```
'''
Developer: Roei Edri
File name: trcrt.py
Date: 24.11.17
Version: 1.1.0
Description: Get an url as an input and prints the traceroute to it.
'''

import sys
import urllib2
i, o, e = sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr 
from scapy.all import *
from scapy.layers.inet import *
sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr = i, o, e


def trcrt(dst):
    """
    Check for the route for the given destination
    :param dst: Final destination, in a form of a website.
    :type dst: str
    """
    try:
        pckt = IP(dst=dst)/ICMP()                        # Creates the 
                                                         # packet
        ip = [p for p in pckt.dst]                       # Gets the ip
        print "Tracerouting for  {0}  :  {1}".format(dst, ip[0])
        for ttl in range(1, 40):
            pckt = IP(ttl=ttl, dst=dst)/ICMP()
            timeBefore = time.time()
            reply = sr1(pckt, verbose=0, timeout=5)
            timeAfter = time.time()
            timeForReply = (timeAfter - timeBefore)*1000
            if reply is not None:
                print "{0} : {1} ; Time for reply: {2}".format(ttl, 
                reply.src, timeForReply)
                if reply.type == 0:
                    print "Tracerout Completed"
                    break
            else:
                print "{0} ... Request Time Out".format(ttl)


def checkInternet():
    """
    Checks if there is an internet connection
    :return: True if there is an internet connection
    """
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen('http://45.33.21.159', timeout=1)
        return True
    except urllib2.URLError as IntError:
        return False
```

Thanks for any help...
Btw pep8 says 
"module level import not at top of file"
for lines 12,13

Comment: the indentation error is in the line "def checkInternet():"

Comment: `def checkInternet():`

Comment: To edit your question, click on the [edit] button at the bottom of the question, just below the `python` and `indentation` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `try` block is missing its `except` clause.

```
try:
    pckt = IP(dst=dst)/ICMP()                        # Creates the 
                                                     # packet
    ip = [p for p in pckt.dst]                       # Gets the ip
    print "Tracerouting for  {0}  :  {1}".format(dst, ip[0])
    for ttl in range(1, 40):
        pckt = IP(ttl=ttl, dst=dst)/ICMP()
        timeBefore = time.time()
        reply = sr1(pckt, verbose=0, timeout=5)
        timeAfter = time.time()
        timeForReply = (timeAfter - timeBefore)*1000
        if reply is not None:
            print "{0} : {1} ; Time for reply: {2}".format(ttl, 
            reply.src, timeForReply)
            if reply.type == 0:
                print "Tracerout Completed"
                break
        else:
            print "{0} ... Request Time Out".format(ttl)

except:   # Here : Add the exception you wish to catch                                    
    pass  # handle this exception appropriately
```

As a general rule, do not use catch all `except` clauses, and do not `pass` on a caught exception, it lets it fail silently.

Comment: i know... the code editor in this forum doesnt allow more words in line so i just moved it to below

Comment: @RoeiEdri - Thats just incorrect, you should create a [mcve] that demonstrates the actual code you're using.

Comment: thats what i meant... in my original code its all in the same line

Comment: I've edited it for you  - I will delete this answer.

Comment: `except:pass` should be prohibited. __Please__ do NOT advise anyone to use it.

Comment: I know; far from me the idea of recommending it, but IDK what exception the OP intended to protect against. I am adding a note in the answer. Thank you for calling me on it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your full code, there are two things to check:
1) Have you mixed tabs and spaces? Make sure that all tabs are converted to spaces (I recommend 4 spaces per tab) for indentation. A good IDE will do this for you.

2) The `try:` in `trcrt(dst)` does not hava a matching except block.

PEP8 will by the way also tell you, that function names should be lowercase:
`check_internet` instead of `checkInternet`, ...

I will give you the same recommendation, that I give to everyone working with me: Start using an IDE that marks PEP8 and other errors for you, there is multiple around. It helps spotting those errors a lot and trains you to write clean Python code that is easily readable and (if you put comments in it) also reausable and understandable a few years later.